# longBitsToDouble, without rounding, is it possible

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I have this piece of code, "text" is forced to example value

```
  public static String binStringToRealString(String text, int precision) {
    String result = "";
    long longBits;
    Double doubleValue;

    text = "0011111111110001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010";

    longBits = Long.parseLong(text, 2);
    Log.d(TAG, "longBits = " + longBits);
    // longBits = 4607632778762754458

    doubleValue = Double.longBitsToDouble(longBits);
    Log.d(TAG, "doubleValue = " + doubleValue);
    // doubleValue = 1.1

    result = doubleValue.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "result = " + result);

    return result;
}
```

Can I somehow get not rounded doubleValue ?

Actual value is 1.10000000000000008881784197001

Like in this converter
http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=3FF199999999999A

What should I do to stop rounding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double` will not display that measure of precision. You will have to use something like `BigDecimal` instead. Simply doing `(new BigDecimal(doubleValue)).toString()` to populate your `result` will do it. However the `String` representation you get from that is `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` which is `22` extra digits than the exact value you posted.

Edit: In fact playing around with different `MathContext` types for the `BigDecimal` constructor I cannot get the exact value that you posted (i.e. value with exactly that many digits) so I am unsure how that value was computed.

```
Your exact value        ->   1.10000000000000008881784197001
MathContext.DECIMAL64   ->   1.100000000000000
MathContext.DECIMAL128  ->   1.100000000000000088817841970012523
MathContext.UNLIMITED   ->   1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

Comment: I guess your results are better then a website, they maybe cut it at some point. Thanks!